# How to fire a trigger after the SPROC has completed execution?

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I have written a trigger that sends email once a row **INSERT** is performed.

```
ALTER TRIGGER TR_SendMailOnDataRequest
      ON DataRequest
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE 
        @DR_Id INT,
        @DR_FullName VARCHAR(200),
        @DR_Email VARCHAR(200),
        @DR_Phone VARCHAR(20),
        @UT_Name VARCHAR(50),
        @DR_UserTypeOther VARCHAR(50) = NULL,
        @D_Name VARCHAR(200),
        @DR_RequestDate DATETIME,
        @UF_LinkedFiles VARCHAR(MAX),
        @DRN_Names VARCHAR(200),
        @DR_Description VARCHAR(1200),
        @DR_CreatedOn DATETIME,
        @analystMailList VARCHAR(MAX),
        @tableHtml NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @downloadLink VARCHAR(MAX) = N'NONE'

    SELECT @DR_Id = MAX(DR_Id) FROM dbo.DataRequest

    SELECT 
        @DR_FullName = DR_FullName,
        @DR_Email = DR_Email,
        @DR_Phone = DR_Phone,
        @UT_Name = UT_Name,
        @DR_UserTypeOther = DR_UserTypeOther,
        @D_Name = D_Name,
        @DR_RequestDate = DR_RequestDate,
        @UF_LinkedFiles = UF_LinkedFiles,
        @DRN_Names = DRN_Names,
        @DR_Description = DR_Description,
        @DR_CreatedOn = DR_CreatedOn
    FROM
        dbo.FN_GetDataRequest(@DR_Id)

    SELECT @analystMailList = dbo.FN_GetAnalystsMailList()

    IF (LEN(@UF_LinkedFiles) > 0)
    BEGIN
        SET @downloadLink = N'<a href="http://localhost:8500/workrequest/index.cfm?event=downloads.index&id=' + CAST(@DR_Id AS VARCHAR(10)) + N'&k='+ SUBSTRING(master.dbo.fn_varbintohexstr(HashBytes('SHA', ':be9[Dcv9wF~W!?xx4JO0OXLbZ@0p4+[~z0dO|:U,OF!13^xZb')), 3, 32) + N'">Downloads</a>'
    END

    SET @tableHTML =
        N'<H1>Data Request</H1>' +
        N'<UL>' +
        N'<LI>Full Name: ' + @UF_LinkedFiles + N'</LI>' +
        N'<LI>Email: ' + @DR_Email + N'</LI>' +
        N'<LI>Phone: ' + CAST(@DR_Phone AS VARCHAR(20)) + N'</LI>' +
        N'<LI>User Type: ' + @UT_Name + N'</LI>' +
        N'<LI>User Type Other: ' + COALESCE(@DR_UserTypeOther, N'NONE') + N'</LI>' +
        N'<LI>Reuest Date: ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), @DR_RequestDate, 107) + N'</LI>' +
        N'<LI>Downloads: ' + @downloadLink + N'</LI>' +
        N'</UL>';

    BEGIN
        EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
            @profile_name = 'Example',
            @recipients = 'John Doe<jdoe@example>',
            --@recipients = @analystMailList,
            @reply_to = @DR_Email,
            @subject = 'Email Test',
            @body_format = 'HTML',
            @body = @tableHtml
    END
END
GO
```

The above trigger is fired when there is a **ROW INSERT** operation on table **DataRequest**. After the row insert operation, I take the **IDENTITY** element generated after the **INSERT** operation and use that as the foreign key, and INSERT other values in a different table. Finally, I use the values from both the tables and create an email to be sent.

I wasn't getting the values from the other tables (e.g. **@UF_LinkedFiles**), so I realized that the **TRIGGER**  is being fired just after the **INSERT** in **FIRST** table but before the **INSERT** in the **SECOND** table, thus no values available when **SENDING EMAIL**.

So how do I make sure that **TRIGGER** is fired only after the SPROC that does all the **INSERT** activities in multiple tables has completed the transaction.

Here is the table diagram - 
[image: Tables]

Comment: You need a trigger on the second table as well.

Comment: There are multiple entries being made to the second table, so the trigger would be fired multiple times. Also there is a third table too where I insert values.

Comment: If your SP is doing insert on both table then you can define the trigger on table2 instead of defining it on table1. That way it will make sure that insert on both table has been done and then trigger is been fired. But then you will also have to make sure that insert does happen successfully on both table or not at all using transaction scope.

Comment: This...  `SELECT @DR_Id = MAX(DR_Id) FROM dbo.DataRequest` is going to give you problems when multiple rows are inserted.  Look into the `inserted` table.  It holds all your new data, theres no need to dip back into the DataRequest table.

Comment: @Rahul - There are multiple tables, to be exact 3.

Comment: Put your trigger logic into a stored proc.  Give it an input parameter for @DR_Id.  Then...insert your record to DataRequest, capture the `MAX(DR_Id)` value (or @@IDENTITY value, if applicable), insert other records to the other table(s), then call your stored proc with @DR_Id.

Comment: If you post all tables, and the proc code, it would be a lot easier than guessing what you're doing :)

Comment: Also, read and heed the comment from @JiggsJedi.  A trigger "fires" once per insert (not once per inserted row).  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: @JiggsJedi - I will be posting later tonight when I reach home from work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using a trigger, I have included the EMAIL SENDING code in the SPROC where rows are being inserted.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if that is your case because you don't explain how is the behavior between the tables. But i had an scenario where i try to execute a `SELECT` during a series of insert and i couldn't find the row because the transaction wasn't finish yet.

What i did was create an additional table

```
tblProgress
    id integer,
    fieldA integer,
    fieldB integer,
    fieldC integer
```

So if you have 3 tables TableA, TableB and TableC each table will have one `INSERT` trigger and will do some job then access tblProgress.

TableA create a row
TableB and TableC update.

Then tblProgress will also have an `AFTER UPDATE` trigger, where you validate all 3 field have `NOT NULL` value

When you have all 3 values you can send the email.